# reduce same function call inside ngFor loop

Tags: typescript, ngfor, angular13, angular14, clarity

inside the ngFor loop, there are 3 same function call - processStatus(status). Is there a way to call it only once inside the for loop by saving it in a parameter , and then refer to that parameter inside the ngFor?

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let status of processCompStatusOrder; let i = index;>
     <div *ngIf="!!processStatus(status)">
         <clr-icon class="icon" [attr.shape]="svc.getIcon(processStatus(status))"></clr-icon>
         {{ 'base.' + processStatus(status)?.toLowerCase() | i18next }}
     </div>
</ng-container>

processStatus(status) {
     return this.process?.[status]?.process?.status; 
 }
```

My attempt below which doesn't work

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let status of processCompStatusOrder; let i = index; let p=processStatus(status)>
     <div *ngIf="!!p">
         <clr-icon class="icon" [attr.shape]="svc.getIcon(p)"></clr-icon>
         {{ 'base.' + p?.toLowerCase() | i18next }}
     </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the result and alisa like
`*ngIf='{status:processStatus(status)}` as result

now you can access the result.status inside that ngif

```
`<ng-container *ngIf='{status: processStatus(status)} as result'>
 <div *ngIf="!!result.status">
     // any where else you can access this property
 </div>
</ng-container>`
```

Also it a better practice to use custom pipes to achieve what the process status function does.
using a function inside a template will almost trigger it for every change detection and might lead to performance issues.
[Angular Pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

Comment: for line 1 *ngIf='{s1: value} as result'.
What does s1 means? and why  need to assign s1 to value